# SharePoint REST API ensureUser call returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, office-365-groups

My API call to my SharePoint site returns a *400 Bad Request* when querying certain **Microsoft 365 groups** with the ensureUser API call.

We have a requirement to use Microsoft 365 groups, so I'm trying to figure out why some work and others do not.  Please take a look at my examples, and let me know if you can help.

I have created a **Microsoft 365 Group**:

[image]

but calling the ensureUser API call returns a *400 Bad Request*:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/DemoTeamSite/_api/web/ensureUser?logonName='Marketing Dept'
```

[image]

I believe I have an identical **Microsoft 365 Group**:

[image]

which returns a *200 OK status*:

[image]

As a sanity check, I created a new **Security group**:

[image]

and confirmed that I can query it:

[image]

FYI, none of these groups exist in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

BTG Social is ID=27 in the user information list on that site. So yes, BTG Social is, or was once, in that SharePoint site. If you add those other groups to the site, they'll come back as well.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of `ensureUser` to make sure that the user is added to the site?  From [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245233(v=office.15)): "Checks whether the specified login name belongs to a valid user in the site. **If the user doesn't exist, adds the user to the site.**"

Comment: ah, yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm your user 'Marketing Dept' still enabled in AD. This error can be occurred as if the user is not enabled in AD, though it will still show as an SP User.